# Fetching an image from backend and sending it to client

Tags: node.js, express, blob

I'm currently trying to fetch an image (on an express server) from a URL that is sent from a form on the client, and send back a blob to the client.

I have something like this:

```
app.post('/upload-image', async (req, res) => {
    let { url } = req.body;
    if (!url) console.log('no url');

    request.get(url, { encoding: null }, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
                console.log(resp);
            } else {
                res.contentType(resp.headers['content-type']);
                res.end(resp.body, 'binary');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now, I'm having a little trouble reading this data on the front end. Would like some advice on how I could read/parse the image and put it into a div on the front end. For now, the front end is simply an index.html file that is served through the same express server.

Comment: downloading files actually has two parts, 1) sending the file correctly, but also 2) handling the file response correctly. I suspect the answer is no - but are you able to download the file independently of your client app (IE a url and a get request)?

Comment: I just edited the code. Now, with postman, the endpoint fetches and returns a response as an image in postman. Now I'm not too sure how to use this response to show the image on the front-end. With the post request, I pass a URL to the image and a filename to identify the image.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch